# C - variable with different value

Tags: c

I have a probleme with my code. The intention of this code is to counting neighbors and modify the array depending of options.
After multiply of test, I observed that the request : `nbVoisins = nb_voisins_M(tab, i, j, n, m);` (who couting neightbors) and the line just after `if(nbVoisins = b)`has not the same value; And I don't understand why...

```
int i, j, k, nbVoisins; int b = 0;int s = 0;

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<m; j++)
    {
    nbVoisins = nb_voisins_M(tab, i, j, n, m);
        if(tab[i][j]==1)
        {
            for(k=0; k<9; k++)
            {
                if(S[k]==1)
                {
                    s = k+1;
                    //printf("tab[%d][%d] : nbVoisins = %d et s = %d \n",i,j,nbVoisins,s);
                    if(nbVoisins == s)
                    {
                        tab2[i][j]=1;
                        printf("= %d",tab2[i][j]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tab2[i][j]=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(k=0; k<9; k++)
            {
                if(B[k]==1)
                {
                    b = k+1;
                }
                if(nbVoisins == b)
                {
                    tab2[i][j]=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had a nickel...

```
if(nbVoisins == b)
```

Because,

```
 if(nbVoisins = b)
```

will assign value of `b` to `nbVoisins`, and then it will check if `nbVoisins` is equal to 0, it will not **compare** `b` and `nbVoisins` for equality.

Decent compilers should [raise a warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hw7c1he%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for this, so pay attention to the warnings - it should be listed.

Comment: Ahhh yes i didn't saw that sorry ... But there is an another probleme. When nbVoisins == s, normally the square of array rest with value of 1 in tab2. It works but after the value changed to 0 ... (I have changed the code on my first post)